# Trying to count rows matching multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, counting

Using Zapier, when someone fills out my Wufoo application form, a line is created with some of the information, including Date Created as well as the locations selected from a checkbox field. On my second sheet, I want to be able to have a total of how many applications have come in just today for each location. I figured the easiest way to do this would be a CountIFs function, but I'm probably wrong.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mIw_O6KT2QCyKeKmZ4aJ1EHzOkZ4xj49ZyjEMOCwUxA/edit#gid=0

Here is a copy of what I'm building if you'd like to experiment. I'm using `=countifs(Sheet1!E2:T1000,"Buford,GA (Atlanta)",Sheet1!E2:T1000,"="&TODAY())` to try to find this, but always get 0 as the result.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

You needed to specify the columns, in your case: `E2:E` to look up for the name, and `S2:S` for the date.

```
=countifs(Sheet1!E2:E,"Buford, GA (Atlanta)",Sheet1!S2:S,"="&TODAY())
```

You can also use Partial Match in order to use your headers in Sheet2 as the first criteria in your countifs:

```
=countifs(Sheet1!E2:E,"*"&B$1&"*",Sheet1!S2:S,"="&TODAY())
```

Then you had a problem of formatting in Sheet1 within the Date's Column (`S`): your second date in cell `S3` was formatted as Date Time, as oppose to your first date in `S2` which was formatted as Date only.

**Note**: The above suggestions are to resolve your personal attempt, otherwise they are other ways of achieving what you're looking for.

**UDPATE (ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION):**

you could use the following QUERY which summarize everything within a table and sort it in descending order:

```
= {"Names","Count";
    ARRAYFORMULA(
        SORT(
            TRANSPOSE(
                SUBSTITUTE(
                    QUERY(Applications!D1:T,
                        "Select Count(D),Count(E), Count(F), Count(G), Count(H), Count(I), Count(J), 
                        Count(K), Count(L), Count(M), Count(N), Count(O), Count(P), Count(Q), Count(R), Count(S) where T = date '"&TEXT(today(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
                        "),
                        "count", "")
                ),
                2, 0)
        )
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I got a lot closer, but I'm still running into some issues that I'm not sure what's causing... 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mIw_O6KT2QCyKeKmZ4aJ1EHzOkZ4xj49ZyjEMOCwUxA/edit#gid=0 

Here is the link again, and the problem I'm running into is that the "Daily Count" sheet seems to only be counting the first two rows of the "Applications" sheet. Everything is working fine within those first two rows, but for example, West Little Rock has three entries in the application sheet, but only shows 2 on the daily count, despite the date and name matching.

Comment: Any more help would be GREATLY appreciated, I'm so close! Thanks again.

Comment: Also, Cinco Ranch doesn't seem to be working at all.... Not sure why

Comment: I've just check now, and after changing the date to 20/3/2021, everything is counted properly

Comment: Have also a look at my updated answer, which provides you with a way of creating a table with one single formula (using QUERY)